# Detect the start tone event for a race from a .wav file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, detection, correlation

I am trying to measure the duration (in samples) between a start tone (3800Hz) and finish tone (high amplitude but frequency unknown). The two tones are randomly distributed in a .wav file (est. 10 seconds). Is it important to identify the sample number of the last sample of the first tone and the first sample of the last tone? How can I do this?

The .wav file contains a fundamental frequency and some noise (as well as the start tone and finish tone). I have a prerecording of the start tone with the fundamental frequency and noise in the background, can i use a correlation function to detect it?

Some of the noise exceeds 3800Hz (instantaneously) so methods using threshold values for the detecting the tones don't work very well. However, can I use the fact that the tone event is longer in duration than any noise event (because it is made deliberately by pressing and releasing a button) to detect the tone.

Comment: This is a very large question. You are asking for a little more than coding help here. Let me suggest an overall method, and let you ask smaller, more pointed questions later.
Have you tried filtering (in frequency domain) to eliminate everything but a band around 3.8kHz.  Then you could threshold the amplitude (time domain) to find that first tone. To find the second,  if you know it it extremely load, you could try thresholding, or low-pass filtering in time domain (try `smooth`) and then thresholding. Sorry this is stream on consciousness. Hope it helps.